# Conditionally output paragraph with inline R chunks

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

In my knitr repport I have several paragraphs that are only relevant if some criteria is met.

Wrapping everything in an inline `r ifelse(...` gets convuluted real fast.

So I tried with a code chunk like this

````
```{r conditional_block, eval=nrow(data)>0, results="asis"}

print("For theese `r nrow(data)` people, the mean salary is `r paste(round(mean(data$sallary),2))` dollars per year")
```
````

I tried with `print`, `paste` and `cat`. And I tired with results `asis` and `markup`. But the output is always - 'raw' the inline R code shows verbatim.

Comment: Do you want to condition on a "flag" to define - you either compile the report with the additional information or without - or dynamically on results you obtain during the calculations?

Comment: In the chunk you are already in an R context - no need for inline r code. Just compose the string with the normal R string functions like `print(sprintf("The number of rows is %s", nrow(data)))`.

Comment: By the way I don't see where you condition on something in your example code chunk...?

Comment: Have you seen [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34599993/2207840)?

Comment: thanks. I clarified the eval statement. @CL. idea with `cat(sprintf(.... ` was what I needed. I hope @CL. will answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Can't you precompute the values (depending on some condition) in a chunk and call them inline?

Comment: Hi @RomanLuštrik - sorry. The points is that its not som much the values as the text that is conditional :-) Eg. "ernings have gone up/down which is bad/ok/good" - this sort of conditional text quickly becomes a mess to do inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the code chunk shown in the question is rather conceptual than technical: The content of the chunk is interpreted as R code. Using `knitr`'s syntax for inline output in the R context is neither possible nor necessary. Instead, the normal string functions should be used to compose the output string:

````
```{r conditional_block, eval=nrow(data)>0, results="asis"}

cat(sprintf(
  "For these %d people, the mean salary is %.2f dollars per year.", 
  nrow(data), mean(data$salary))
  )
```
````