# How to include a header based on a condition in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I have a header followed by a code chunk in an Rmd file. I only want to include this header and the chunk followed by it, if a condition is met. I know how to do that with the chunk, since it's in the body of the code, but how do I do the former?

````
```{r}
 print_option <- TRUE
```

## My header
```{r}
 if(print_option==TRUE) {
 print (x)
 }
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out :)

````
    ```{r, echo=FALSE,  include=FALSE}
    x<- FALSE
    if ( x ) {
      Title <- "My header"
    } else {Title=""}
    ```
    ## `r Title` 
    ```{r, echo=FALSE}
    if(x) {
    print(1:10)
    }
    ```
````

Comment: This is not a good idea; it leaves you with an "empty header" `##` if `x` is not `TRUE`.

Comment: No, it doesn't. ## is just for the font size. If nothing is in front of it, it will be blank.

Comment: It does. See the addendum in my answer below.

Answer (score 14):

The [chunk option](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/) `eval` and `asis_output()` provide a simple solution.

Assuming that `print_option` is a boolean indicating whether to show the header (and whether to execute other code like `print(1:10)` in chunk `example1`):

````
```{r setup}
library(knitr)
print_option <- TRUE
```

```{r, eval = print_option}
asis_output("## My header\\n") # Header that is only shown if print_option == TRUE
print(1:10) # Other stuff that is only executed if print_option == TRUE
```

Text that is shown regardless of `print_option`.

```{r setup2}
print_option <- FALSE
```

Now `print_option` is `FALSE`. Thus, the second header is not shown.

```{r, eval = print_option}
asis_out("## Second header\\n")
```
````

**Output:**

[image: Output]

For longer conditional outputs (of text/markdown, without embedded R code) the [engine](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/engines/) `asis` can be helpful, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641628/2706569) (it's long, but the solution at the end is very concise).

### Addendum

Why is `` ## `r Title` `` with `Title` set to `"My header"` or `""` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35590642/2706569) a bad idea? Because it creates an "empty header" in the second case. This header is *not visible* in the rendered HTML/markdown output, but it is still there. See the following example:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
title <- ""
```

## `r title`
````

This generates the following markdown ...

```
##
```

... and HTML:

```
<h2></h2>
```

Besids being semantically nonsense it might lead to layout issues (depending on the style sheet) and disrupts the document outline.

Comment: Thanks @CL. 
The only problem with your solution is that it will print the rest of the code output in the chunk like text.

Comment: @Asieh I suppose you're referring to the linked answer, right? Or is anything wrong with the `cat` solution here?

Comment: No, I'm referring to your answer, though the linked solution gives the same output. It is about the format of the output code in the chunk that is different from the normal output format. I just wanted to have the option to include the header or not. I did not want to change the output format of the code.

Comment: @Asieh thank you for the feedback. I'm writing from my phone at the moment but I will look into this again later when I'm back at the laptop....

Comment: @AsiehHarati Updated the answer. If you were referring to the formatting of the output from `print(1:10)`, that's fixed now. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding the question.