# Drop a set of R markdown lines

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Is there a way to skip a set of code lines in R Markdown (knitr) given a condition?

If some condition is reached, I want to skip a set of lines (e.g, drop lines 60-100 if something is TRUE) including code (´´´< >´´´) and text (**text**).
Or maybe something like a GOTO.

Comment: I'm not sure if its appropriate to tag this with 'markdown' in this context of "R Markdown" in specific.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is overly-broad, or a duplicate, along the lines of "R Markdown conditional statement/block".

Comment: See https://yihui.name/knitr/options/, specifically "Code Evaluation" and "Text Results".

Comment: More the point, the argument provided to `eval=` can be numeric, and that numeric vector can be conditioned on something else in the R environment.

Comment: This also may be helpful for conditionally executing code using a `param` in the YAML header: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550732/is-there-a-way-to-have-conditional-markdown-chunk-execution-in-rmarkdown

Comment: Yeah, I can switch the <eval=> given a condition, but imagine two chunks for whose there's text between, then if <eval=0> for both, the code won’t be runed but the text stills apearing.

Comment: I want a way to skip the code and also the *text*.

Comment: Could you put lines 60-100 in a separate file and evaluate that file as a child of the main document?