# Run a different Rchunk based on what option defined in YAML header (params)?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am attempting my first [Rmarkdown Parameterized report](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html).  The first section will download a dataset from one of two sources (and internal vs external database) based on the params 'dataSource' selected by the user.  The Rscript/code required is different for the different options.

```
title: "Optionally DL from external vs internal database"
output: html_document
params:
  dataSource: 
    label: "Select the database for download:"
    value: IntD
    input: radio
    choiceNames: [External DB, Internal DB]
    choiceValues: [ExtD, IntD]
    inline: TRUE
```

The following code does work, but **is there a way to optionally run an entire Rchunk based on a params selection (some code put directly in the Rchunk header, for example)?**

````
```{r downloadData, include=TRUE}

#Can I run different rchunk or code based on the params$dataSource value??
#Can this be done directly in the Rchunk header?

if(params$dataSource=="IntD"){
 source(here::here("R", "Intdownload.R")
}else{
 source(here::here("R", "Extdownload.R")
}
```
````

Other options I've explored (and am working on understanding how to implement) are listed below.   **Are any of these better options to investigate if download code is likely to be used in other reports/Rscript/Rmarkdown documents?**  I am a bit confused as to when these might be better than using 'source'?

- creating seperate chunks in an external Rscript and use [read_chunk to read in the external script](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/), then call each chunk based on the params option selected.
- Creating a separate Rmarkdown document for datadownload, and then calling that within this Rmarkdown document using [child](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/).   Does this option essentially allow you to create 2 reports (1 by calling a child Rmarkdown doc, and another for main Rmarkdown document) while using objects created in the child document in the main document?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550732/is-there-a-way-to-have-conditional-markdown-chunk-execution-in-rmarkdown

Comment: You can pass a variable to `eval` in the chunk options. I did this recently with a parameterized document where different combinations of chunks needed to be run or skipped. The variable `params$to_eval` was a named list of true/false for each chunk, included like this: `eval=to_eval[["health"]]`

Comment: @camille - interesting, but I need to evaluate based on the value of another params value (in the case which database was used).   I found the following allowed me to optionally evaluate the chunk based on a params value.     `{r downloadData, eval=FALSE || params$dataSource=="IntD"}`

Comment: @Wil  - Not exactly what I was looking for, but you did answer a question I was trying to find a solution for. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to review ?`||`, but I believe `eval=FALSE || params$dataSource==“IntD”` will always proceed to take the value of `params$dataSource==“IntD”`, and `FALSE ||` is unnecessary. Do you find that the code fails unless you include the `FALSE ||” component?

Comment: @Wil - You are correct the `FALSE || ` is not needed.  I had taken the idea from elsewhere - it did seem odd, but perhaps their condition needed it.