# How to correct render code results from a markdown chunk

Tags: r-markdown

This is my MWE for a `.Rmd` file:

````
    ---
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---

Uma vez que a `r vd` é medida numa escala `r ifelse(class_vd[1]=="ordered", "ordinal, o teste a usar é o Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney", "quantitativa, o teste a usar é o t-Student se:")`

`r testarpress <- class_vd[1]=="numeric"`

#now I want to run a chunk with latex and text alike if `testarpress==TRUE`

```{echo=testarpress, eval=testarpress}

- $`r vd`_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma_i);i=`r grupo[1]`,`r grupo[2]`$ --- $`r ifelse(sum(SW$norm) > 1, "Verifica-se.", "Rejeita-se.")`$

- $\sigma^2_{`r grupo[1]`}=\sigma^2_{`r grupo[2]`}$ ---  $`r ifelse(Lev$homosc[1], "Verifica-se.", "Rejeita-se.")`$
````

What I want is to just write the text inside the `press` chunk if `testarpress==TRUE` and skip the `press` chunk if not. This is the output I get:

[image]

I get the correct substitutions, but everything is rendered as code, with no latex in the $\mu$ blocks.

`cat` is not a solution, because the chunk is a full page of text and formulae and r values...

Any idea if this can be accomplished and how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after [Is there a way to have conditional markdown chunk execution in Rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550732/is-there-a-way-to-have-conditional-markdown-chunk-execution-in-rmarkdown) the solution was quite simple, and clean:

```
Uma vez que a `r vd` é medida numa escala `r ifelse(class_vd[1]=="ordered", "ordinal, o teste a usar é o Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney", "quantitativa, o teste a usar é o t-Student se:")`

`r testarpress <- class_vd[1]=="numeric"`


`r if(testarpress) {"\\begin{comment}"}`

Put your md code here...

`r if(testarpress) {"\\end{comment}"}`
```

I did not know the  {"\begin{comment}"} feature... ;--)