# Rmarkdown output rendering based on condition

Tags: r, if-statement, r-markdown, cpu-word

I am trying to build in an automated way a Word document that will display a list of Youtube video links I want to watch with Youtube Title video as text and the Youtube url as a hyperlink.

I have used Rmarkdown to do that and it works well with a defined number of urls.
But my issue is that I want that Rmarkdown document to work with any number of urls as input of my `Links.txt` file.

As an example, the content of the `Links.txt` file could simply be:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NDDUMon9SJM  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9iAD3GZyfM  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHhNWAKw0bY  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYUZAF3ePFE  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ik4USIChrkY  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgEGAaYdABA
```

Is there a way to use a if condition of some sort to display the exact number of urls each time?

The only post that seems related is this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407102/conditionally-display-a-block-of-text-in-r-markdown) but I don't really see a working solution.

Here is my current code:

````
---
title: "Hyperlinks_Word"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library('rvest')
library('magrittr')
library('httr')

```


```{r }

url_proxy <- read.table("Links.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "")

url_proxy <- as.character(url_proxy$V1)

link_test <- list()

for(i in 1:length(url_proxy)){
  
  download.file(url_proxy[i], destfile ='scrape_test.html',quiet = TRUE)
  
  url <- read_html('scrape_test.html')
  
  youtube_title <- url%>%html_nodes(xpath = "//title")%>%html_text()
  youtube_title <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(youtube_title), nrow=length(youtube_title), byrow=T))
  colnames(youtube_title) <- "youtube_title"

  link_test[i] <- as.character(youtube_title$youtube_title)
  
}


```


`r i=1`

[`r link_test[i]`](`r url_proxy[i]`)  

`r i=2`

[`r link_test[i]`](`r url_proxy[i]`)  

`r i=3`

[`r link_test[i]`](`r url_proxy[i]`)  

`r i=4`

[`r link_test[i]`](`r url_proxy[i]`)
````

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking. What is your condition to display the URL? Or do you simply want to display _all_ the names and URLs in the Links.txt file without having to write inline code for each individual entry?

Comment: yes, the answer to your last question is yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add the following to the chunk

`cat(paste0("[", unlist(link_test), "](", url_proxy,")", collapse="\n\n"))`

`paste0` takes care of creating the hyperlinks by pasting title and URL together. Using double `\n` to create sufficient line break.

Use `results='asis'` in chunk options.

````
```{r, results='asis'}

url_proxy <- read.table("Links.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "")

url_proxy <- as.character(url_proxy$V1)

link_test <- list()

for(i in 1:length(url_proxy)){
  
  download.file(url_proxy[i], destfile ='scrape_test.html',quiet = TRUE)
  
  url <- read_html('scrape_test.html')
  
  youtube_title <- url%>%html_nodes(xpath = "//title")%>%html_text()
  youtube_title <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(youtube_title), nrow=length(youtube_title), byrow=T))
  colnames(youtube_title) <- "youtube_title"

  link_test[i] <- as.character(youtube_title$youtube_title)
  
}


cat(paste0("[", unlist(link_test), "](", url_proxy,")", collapse="\n\n"))
```
````