# Nest different chunks within an rmd child file

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, knitr, bookdown

I'm using a master-child file approach to structure my rmd project and build it with Bookdown to generated both a Word document and a git_book site. What I want to achieve is some kind parameter-controlled compilation (using the knitr block engine mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58333141/14253488)).

For example, my index.Rmd will have its YAML like this:

```
params:
  RootTitle: true
  Demand: false
  FeatureDesign: true
  TitleApp: true
```

Then the child rmd will be structured like this:

````
```{block eval=FALSE, include=params$RootTitle}
# Research
Some text
```

```{block eval=FALSE, include=params$Demand}
## Customer's demand
Some text
```
```{block eval=FALSE, include=params$FeatureDesign}
# Feature design
## Primary features
Some text

## Secondary features
Some text

```
````

And i do this for every child rmd files to be included. Then I can switch off a certain part (like the feature design part) of all the child files by simply change FeatureDesign to false in params.

The problem is how will I insert images in these rmd files? I have two choices:

1. the markdown vanilla way : `![title](image.jpg)`, but you can't have centered images in git_book site with this approach.
2. the rmarkdown way, which can have centered images

   ` ``{r, fig.align = 'center', fig.cap = ""}

   knitr::include_graphics("")

   ` ``

The problem is, I now have to nested an r code chunk into the block chunk, with will have mixed backticks and warnings are thrown:

> Warning messages: 1: In hook(x[i], reduce_plot_opts(options)) : Chunk options fig.align is not supported for docx output

> 2: In xfun::prose_index(content) : Code fences are not balanced

> 3: In xfun::prose_index(content) : Code fences are not balanced

and the result git_book or docx have [trailing backticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcm92.png)

[here's a minimum example](https://github.com/kmcbest/markdowndocs/raw/master/bookdowndemo2.zip) :

Comment: Can you use childs of childs ? So that text in your blocks are in a normal Rmd file ?
I think eval=FALSE won't show them.

Comment: Your link is dead ..

Comment: Which link? The example file? It's on github raw and I've tested it, it can be downloaded.