# Conditonal RMarkdown inline text

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to conditionally print out text in a Rmarkdown notebook I am writing to automate a report for a project. I have found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407102/conditionally-display-a-block-of-text-in-r-markdown) to conditionally print out text in the rmarkdown notebook using the the code below:

```
`r if(show.text){"la la la"}`
```

Which would print out inline, "la la la" if the show.text object is true. What I would like to know is how to use functions within the brackets, for example:

```
`r if(show.text){print(x)}`
```

The code above does not work. I would like to be able to combine this to make a more complicated conditional

```
`r if(show.text){"la la la" print(x) "bi bi bi" if(y)"bla bla bla"}`
```

But this does not work. Can anyone help me or tell me if this is possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your if-statement is not set up quite correctly. You should use `if`, with the condition in curly brackets and then `else` also in curly brackets. Instead you put an `if`inside another `if`.  Correcting that and use `paste0` to convert your vectors into a string should work. Let me know if that is what you are looking for:

````
```{r showTrue}
show_text=TRUE
x= "my variable x is true"
y= "my variable y is false"
```

Text true: `r if(show_text){paste0("My text shows: ", x , " here")} else{paste0("Otherwise: my text is " , y, " instead")}`

```{r showFalse}
show_text= FALSE
x= "my variable x is true"
y= "my variable y is false"
```

Text false: `r if(show_text){paste0("My text shows: ", x , "here")} else{paste0("Otherwise: my text is " , y, " here")}`
````

[image]