# Conditional Headings Including Variables in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

While I was drafting this question, I was able to find a viable solution, but I decided to share my result, since I am unable to comment on the original with this addition, in case it helps someone else down the line & potentially someone on here knows a cleaner solution.

I have a singular report that shows various different time frames as outputs with accompanying headers. Based on the desire at the moment, I want to be able to quickly decide which of the timeframes will display for a given compilation. The table portion is rather easy using a variable at the beginning of the report, which I flip between `TRUE` and `FALSE` using the following setup:

```
display_month <- TRUE
display_quarter <- FALSE
```

Then incorporating the variable into `eval =` option of the code chunks.

`{r MONTH, echo = FALSE, eval = display_month}`

`{r QUARTER, echo = FALSE, eval = display_quarter}`

However, these code chunks are preceded by headings generated by other variables set at the beginning of the report as well.

```
month <- "OCTOBER"
quarter <- "Q4"
```

And inserted as headings:

```
#### ***`r quarter` DATA***
```

I am looking to continue to use these variables in the headings, while also applying the logic for them to appear only when the corresponding code chunk does.

I found a pretty useful thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/42076080/20873694 which details including a header conditionally:

````
```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
show_text <- FALSE```

```{r conditional_block, echo=FALSE, results='asis', eval=show_text}
cat("## Hey look, a heading!")```
````

However, I have been unsuccessful in implementing the variables with formatting applied as the quotes negate the function within and print the text.

Some variations I have attempted

`cat("#### ***quarter DATA***")` -> ***quarter DATA***

`cat("#### ***",quarter,"DATA","***")` -> *** Q4 DATA ***

**SOLUTION**

Finally, I was able to achieve the desired result using the `paste0()` function with the form of:

`cat("####", paste0("***",quarter," ","DATA","***"))` -> ***Q4 DATA***

It appears that `paste0()` will evaluate the variable within, then allows `cat()` to generate the appropriate header formatting.